# Why does R think the projection data are different?

Tags: r, spatial

I'm working with satellite tracked animals and have a load of relocation data.

So I have my map data and relocations as SpatialPointsDataFrames and when I ask

`if proj4string(map)==proj4string(locs)` I get TRUE.

But when I try the count.points function as follows

```
cp <- count.points(locs, map)
```

I get the following error

```
Error in count.points(SpatialPoints(x), w) : 
  different proj4string in w and xy
```

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is the case?

**Edit**  Code:

```
load("mydata") 
map = mydata$map 
map 
mimage(map) 
locs= mydata$relocs 
locs 
image(map) 
points(locs, col=as.numeric(slot(locs, "data")[,1]), pch=16) 
cp <- count.points(locs, map)
```

Comment: What package is `count.points` from?

Comment: It turns out there is a bug in this function. It'll be fixed in the next patch.

Answer (score 2):

Reproducible example would go a long, long way here.  But generally speaking R's comparison of projection strings is approximately verbatim.  So if there's an extra space or so forth, it will fail.

Given the out for `proj4string(map)`, `proj4string(locs)`, `proj4string(SpatialPoints(locs))` in the comment, particularly that `proj4string(SpatialPoints(locs))` is `NA`, I'd say that `count.points` is dropping the `proj4string` when it changes to a `SpatialPoints` object.  I think the way to coerce a `SPDF` to `SP` while keeping the projection string is via `as(x,"SpatialPoints")`....  Try using `trace` to insert that into `count.points`?

Comment: proj4string(map) is "+init=EPSG:32736 +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0" proj4string(locs) is "+init=EPSG:32736 +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs +towgs84=0,0,0" proj4string(SpatialPoints(locs)) is NA. Thanks!

Comment: So if I use as(x,"SpatialPoints") for the location data I get: Error in checkSlotAssignment(object, name, value) : assignment of an object of class "numeric" is not valid for slot "data" in an object of class "SpatialPixelsDataFrame"; is(value, "data.frame") is not TRUE

Comment: Is it a `SpatialPixelsDF` or a `SpatialPoints` one?  Can you reproduce the problem with a smaller version of your objects and post that here?  It's nearly impossible to debug without knowing either the function or having data to reproduce.

Comment: load("mydata")
    map = mydata$map
    map
    mimage(map) 

    locs= mydata$relocs
    locs
    image(map)
    points(locs, col=as.numeric(slot(locs, "data")[,1]), pch=16)

    cp <- count.points(locs, map)

Comment: Hi Ari, see above for the full code I'm using in the analysis. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @killbot2000 Best to edit the question for things like this.  I've done it for you.  Also, need data to make it reproducible.  Please [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for posting guidelines.

Comment: Hi Ari, could I email you a csv file of a sample of my data? Might be easier to see my problem that way. Thanks